# Ubuntu crashes from a bootable USB

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 using an Ubuntu live USB. I used that software which mounts and prepares the USB with the disk image. When I attempt to boot from my USB from BIOS, when it gets to installing all I can see on screen is:

```
sendbytes: Nak bailout.
[sdd] No caching mode page found
[sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

Whenever I try to *Try Ubuntu without installing* it says

```
Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)
i2c isc-24: sendbytes: NAK bailout
```

It will crash on these screens forever and I have to force power down the PC in order to try again (the reset button on the PC does nothing).

Specs:

- CPU: Intel Core i7 3770k 4GHz
- mobo: Z77 extreme
- RAM: 16GB
- GPU: 2 x Nvidia GTX 780 (SLI)
- SSD: 2 x Sandisk 128GB
- HDD: WD

Comment: Try this. When you get to the screen where you can choose whether to try or install Ubuntu, highlight the "try" option and press `e`. At the end of the line beginning with `linux`, type `nouveau.modeset=0` and press F10 to boot.

Comment: What program did you use to make the USB drive?

Comment: Hi I used the UUI (universal usb installer) to mount my disk image of ubuntu to a 2 gb kingston drive

Comment: I will try the thing you said to make it work

Comment: I tried putting that text in at the end, I wasnt sure what you meant by the end of the line so I assumed after the -- at the very end with a space seperating the -- and the above text you suggested I should put in. Anyways I did that and did F10 to boot it, it still hung on black screen with the same text, I assume I did it wrong since there was no change.

Comment: Is there no one who knows whats wrong? anyone? I really wanna try out ubuntu but this... hiccup is in the way.